# Apache Virtual Host Redirect: *.example.com to www.example.com

Tags: apache-config

I'm simply trying to redirect any example.com to www.example.com. The redirect currently sends example.com to www.example.com//.

The following code is in my virtual host configuration file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^suksanvillas\.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.suksanvillas.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This seems to be what all the tutorials suggest, but I'm unable to understand how I'm picking up the extra "/" on the redirect. Any help on even where I might look is appreciated.

PS: Other subdomains, for examples "guides.examples.com" should not be redirected.

Thanks.

Comment: In case I wasn't clear, the redirect is appending an extra "/" at the end of the url. For example, the url "ht tp://example.com" redirects to "ht tp://www.example.com//"

Answer (score 0):

Avoid capturing the leading slash by using "^/" in the beginning of the pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ ...
```

With that small change everything should work great.

Comment: I'm afraid that that didn't fix the issue. I don't notice any change in behavior, actually.

Comment: @Joe: That is the proper solution (works over here), are you sure you reloaded Apache with the new conf? Are there perhaps other RewriteRules interfering?

Comment: I'm running Google Weboptomizer, which may be redirecting as well. Once that's one I'll check again. Thanks for your help on this. I'll update you once Weboptomizer is removed.